# R: Stationarity/non-Stationarity: implementing a solution

Tags: r, panel-data, stationarity, unit-root

I have an Augmented Dickey Fuller Test in R on `leg_totalbills` that shows I can not reject the null hypothesis: Unit Root. The `panel regression` that it refers to follows:

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

t test of coefficients:

                        Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
cfcontrol            -6.2618e-02  4.0643e-02 -1.5407 0.123527   
amtsum                7.7718e-05  2.5914e-05  2.9991 0.002735 **
unemplag_1           -8.0897e-03  1.2185e-02 -0.6639 0.506798   
leg_totalbills        3.3680e-02  1.2010e-02  2.8043 0.005083 **
amtsum_post2009years -3.9341e-08  1.2988e-08 -3.0289 0.002480 **
amtsum_5to9exp        4.9215e-05  8.2993e-05  0.5930 0.553236   
amtsum_10to19exp     -2.1085e-05  3.8516e-05 -0.5474 0.584124   
amtsum_20exp          2.2601e-05  2.0130e-05  1.1228 0.261653   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Total Sum of Squares:    1755.6
Residual Sum of Squares: 1565.7
R-Squared:      0.1082
Adj. R-Squared: 0.1074
F-statistic: 36.64 on 8 and 2416 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

When I run the same regression without `leg_totalbills` I get the following output:

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model
Unbalanced Panel: n=10, T=41-444, N=2434

Residuals :
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-2.03000 -0.39500 -0.19800 -0.00907 10.40000 
t test of coefficients:

                        Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
cfcontrol             1.6281e-02  5.2280e-02  0.3114 0.7555022    
amtsum                1.0355e-04  2.6742e-05  3.8723 0.0001107 ***
unemplag_1           -1.1543e-02  1.3483e-02 -0.8561 0.3920043    
amtsum_post2009years -5.3029e-08  1.4348e-08 -3.6960 0.0002239 ***
amtsum_5to9exp        1.3603e-04  1.1062e-04  1.2297 0.2189132    
amtsum_10to19exp      1.8843e-05  2.2286e-05  0.8455 0.3979221    
amtsum_20exp          5.2349e-05  2.8275e-05  1.8514 0.0642311 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1Total Sum of Squares:    1755.6
Residual Sum of Squares: 1722.2
R-Squared:      0.019026
Adj. R-Squared: 0.018893
F-statistic: 6.69688 on 7 and 2417 DF, p-value: 7.058e-08

dftest <- CADFtest(femodel_1$leg_totalbills, max.lag.y = 1)
summary(dftest)
```

The Augmented Dickey Fuller test follows:

```
                                                ADF test
t-test statistic:                          -3.446944e+01
p-value:                                    6.388754e-58
Max lag of the diff. dependent variable:    1.000000e+00

Call:
dynlm(formula = formula(model), start = obs.1, end = obs.T)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
 -1840   -369   -253    -13  92819 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 550.710311  86.694498   6.352 2.52e-10 ***
trnd          0.015206   0.060595   0.251    0.802    
L(y, 1)      -0.982389   0.028500 -34.469  < 2e-16 ***
L(d(y), 1)   -0.003719   0.020296  -0.183    0.855    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2098 on 2428 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.493, Adjusted R-squared:  0.4924 
F-statistic:    NA on NA and NA DF,  p-value: NA
```

My interpretation is that I *can* reject the null hypothesis: Unit Root.

Otherwise, The difference is significant with respect to the R squared. I'm wondering if there is a way to correct for the unit root in `leg_totalbills` so that I can keep it in the regression.

Comment: (+1) But it helps to expand acronyms (CADF?); &, when your question revolves around software output, to at least give the command that produced it. A little more detail on "I have read that one can take first differences and that one can standardize" might also be useful. Anyway, are you sure that's the null hypothesis?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the question to address some of your suggestions. In truth, I am not sure that the null Hypothesis is unit-root. I am trying to find some information on that now. Honestly, I am not sure how to proceed in the event that I do have unit-root, nor if I indeed do have unit-root.

Comment: @ Scortchi: I have verified that the null hypothesis in presence of `unit-root`

Comment: Thanks for improving your question. (1) The paper suggests CADF stands for "Covariate Augmented Dickey-Fuller". (2) Even after the edit you still say "I cannot reject the null hypothesis of *no* unit root".

Comment: `CADFtest` is implemented in the package of the same name, not in `plm`, so I wonder why you refer to the `plm` package here. Also, the way use use `CADFtest` with default option `X=NULL` means that you do not use any covariate to augment your ADF regression. Thus you perform a standard ADF test.

Comment: Also, it is not "Audjusted" DF test, but "augmented", please edit

Comment: Well, you might explain your situation here too! Especially if you want guidance on what to do next &c.